# Continuous Perceptron Weights Change Zero

Tags: c#, neural-network, perceptron

I am working on 2 class simple perceptron problem. My project work getting user mouse click from GUI panel and make classification. Class 1 expected output: 1 and Class 2 expected output -1. My problem is discrete perceptron working fine but continuous perceptron after one point stop decrease error. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I look so much code and source.

My formulas;

- E=1/2 Σ(d-o)^2
- f(net)=(2/(1+ⅇ^(-net)))-1
- ΔW=n(d-o)(1-o^2)y

like this.

`d`: Expected output,

`net`: weight*input sum,

`y`: input matrix ([x1 x2 -1]) and

`o`: Actual output.

Code for continuous perceptron below;

```
while (totalError > Emax)
{
   totalError = 0;
   for(i=0; i<point.Count; i++)
   {
       double x1 = point[i].X1;
       double x2 = point[i].X2;
       double net = (x1 * w0) + (x2 * w1) + (x0 * w2);
       double o = (2 / (1 + Math.Exp(-net))) - 1;
       double error = Math.Pow(point[i].Class - o, 2);
       w0 += (x1 * c * (point[i].Class - o) * (1 - Math.Pow(o, 2))) / 2;
       w1 += (x2 * c * (point[i].Class - o) * (1 - Math.Pow(o, 2))) / 2;
       w2 += (x0 * c * (point[i].Class - o) * (1 - Math.Pow(o, 2))) / 2;
       totalError += error;
   }
   totalError = totalError / 2;
   ErrorShow(cycle, totalError);
   objGraphic.Clear(Color.White);
   DrawSeperationLine();
   cycle++;
}
```

Emax=0.001 selected. Project working like this. You can see it not correct line location. Class 1 is blue and class 2 red.

I think problem in for loop.

[image: Project working like this. You can see it not correct shape.]

Console Output of Code:

[image: Console Output]

**Edit:**
After discuss with @TaW (Thanks for showing road), I find out my problem in output (activation function). It always return 1 or -1. After that in weight change function [`1-Math.Pow(o,2)`] part return 0 and that make weight change equal 0. So my question how can I solve this problem. Type casting not work.

Comment: _stop decrease error_ Mraning what? An error message of wrng results? Did you try the debugger to see at which point things go wrong? Did you test your `DrawSeperationLine` function?

Comment: @TaW Thanks for comment. Discrete perceptron use same functions with different learning function. DrawSeperationLine() function working fine in discrete perceptron so I don't think it is problem. If you want I can add DrawSeperationLine function to question. I only have run timeout error message because my iteration go until totalError<Emax and it is not decrease some point. I try debug with Console.WriteLine. Stop decrease error meaning start with totalError=10 but after some cycle stop on totalError=4 or another value. It never decrease to 0.xx value.

Comment: OK, no need to show the functon imo. - if  Console.WriteLine isn't enough do use the actual [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), your very best friend in the world of coding.

Comment: @TaW I think problem is activation function's Math.Exp value. When divide with Exp activation function value is so small not have any effect on weight change. But I can't change formula so I am stuck.

Comment: @TaW Firstly thanks for advice. I use debugger and like I said in above comment Exp value so big output (activation function) value so small and that make my weight change almost zero. My output value -1 or 1 so in weight change (1-Math.Pow(o,2)) part equal 0. And that make change of weights equal 0. Now my question how can I solve this?

Comment: Sounds like a math issue; maybe the folks over at https://math.stackexchange.com/ have advice. In any case I suggest to edit the question to reflect this better..

Comment: @TaW Thanks for advice until now. O am gonna change question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question's solution is using normalization. For normalization I use standard deviation. Standart deviation code is below;

```
for(i=0;i<point.Count;i++){
   x1 += point[i].X1;
   x2 += point[i].X2;
}
meanx1 = x1 / point.Count;
meanx2 = x2 / point.Count;
for(i=0;i<point.Count;i++){
   totalX1 += Math.Pow(point[i].X1 - meanx1, 2);
   totalX2 += Math.Pow(point[i].X2 - meanx2, 2);
}
normX1 = totalX1 / (point.Count - 1);
normX2 = totalX2 / (point.Count - 1);

normX1 = normX1 / 100;
normX2 = normX2 / 100;
```

The last division is used to decrease the value.